# What is the function of {:-9} in python?

Tags: python-3.x

In the Python tutorial (https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/inputoutput.html) they used {:-9}, and i cant figure out for the life of me what the -9 does?:

```
yes_votes = 42_572_654
no_votes = 43_132_495
percentage = yes_votes / (yes_votes + no_votes)
'{:-9} YES votes  {:2.2%}'.format(yes_votes, percentage)
```

Output:
42572654 YES votes  49.67%

Comment: Just guessing: the minus sign may mean "before the decimal point".

Comment: If the number is >0 and has <9 digits or if the number is <0 and has <8 digits, if fills it with spaces. Maybe someone finds docs  to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:-9` value indicates padding. If you remove the `-` the effect will be the same.

However, according to the docs, the `-` indicates that a sign should be used only for negative numbers (this is the default behavior).

Example:

`Replacing %+f, %-f, and % f and specifying a sign`:

```
>>> '{:+f}; {:+f}'.format(3.14, -3.14)  # show it always
'+3.140000; -3.140000'
>>> '{: f}; {: f}'.format(3.14, -3.14)  # show a space for positive numbers
' 3.140000; -3.140000'
>>> '{:-f}; {:-f}'.format(3.14, -3.14)  # show only the minus -- same as '{:f}; {:f}'
'3.140000; -3.140000'
```

More on Python's Format Specification Mini-Language can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec)